# Cadlag process and measurability.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,(\mathcal{F_t})_{t\geq0},P)$ be a filtered probability space and $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ a real-valued adapted cadlag process. Let $A\subset\Omega$ (resp. $B\subset\Omega$) be the event that $X$ is continuous (resp right-continuous) on $[0,t)$.

Show that $A$, $B\in\mathcal{F_t}$.

I am not to show how to show this for $A$ but is it not trivial for $B$ as since $X$ is cadlag, we must then have $B=\Omega$??

Any help is most welcomed and needed. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, if $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is cadlag, then $B=\Omega$.

Comment: Any ideas on how to show $A\in\mathcal{F_t}$?

Answer (score 5):

If $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is càdlàg, then it follows from the very definition that $B=\Omega$, so there is nothing to show.

In order to show $A \in \mathcal{F}_t$, we note that

$$\begin{align*} A &= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \underbrace{\{\omega; [0,t-1/n] \ni s \mapsto X_s(\omega) \, \text{is (uniformly) cts.}\}}_{=:A_n}, \end{align*}$$

i.e. it suffices to show $A_n \in \mathcal{F}_t$. As $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is càdlàg, we know that the limits

$$\begin{align*} X(t-) &:= \lim_{s \uparrow t} X(s)  = \lim_{\mathbb{Q} \ni s \uparrow t} X(s) \tag{1} \\ X(t) &= \lim_{s \downarrow t} X(s) = \lim_{\mathbb{Q} \ni s \downarrow t} X(s) \tag{2} \end{align*}$$

exist for all $t \geq 0$. Therefore,

$$A_n = \{\omega; \forall s \in [0,t-1/n]: X(s-,\omega) = X(s,\omega)\}.$$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have

$$\begin{align*} &\forall s \in [0,t-1/n]: X(s-,\omega) = X(s,\omega)\\  &\iff  \{\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0: r,s \in [0,t-1/n] \cap \mathbb{Q}, |r-s| \leq \delta \Rightarrow |X(r,\omega)-X(s,\omega)| \leq \epsilon\} \end{align*}$$

Consequently,

$$A_n = \bigcap_{i \geq 1} \bigcup_{j \geq 1} \bigcap_{\substack{r,s \in [0,t-1/n] \cap \mathbb{Q} \\ |r-s| \leq \frac{1}{j}}} \left\{ |X(r)-X(s)| \leq \frac{1}{i} \right\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t- \frac{1}{n}} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_t.$$

Comment: Thank you. I see you use uniform continuity as continuous function on a compact domain is uniform but can you argue with just plain continuity? Also I was just wondering if even the cadlag assumption is needed, and if $X$ was just adapted won't we still have $A\in\mathcal{F}_t$  because of the denseness of the rationals? So just use $A_n:=\{\omega\space :\space (\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall s,r\in[0,t-1/n]\cap\mathbb{Q})(|r-s|\leq\delta\Rightarrow|X(r,\omega)-X(s,\omega)|\leq\epsilon)\}$.

Comment: @Edwyn No, if we do not know that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is cadlag, then we cannot use this argumentation. Just consider e.g. $f(x) := 1_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}(x)$. Then $f$ is not continuous, but for any two rationals $r,s \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ we have $$|f(r)-f(s)|=0.$$

Comment: Ok so by the left limit existing, that then makes your equation (1) valid?

Comment: @Edwyn Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you again you really helped me a lot. I saw you edited my other post on the tower property and stopping times, do you have any ideas for that question. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: $t-1/n$ may not be a rational number. We may let $\{a_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,t)$ be a sequence such that $a_n\uparrow t$, and define $A_n$ with $[0,t-1/n]$ replaced by $[0,a_n]$.