# Measurability of the set where sample path is continuous

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and let $(X_t)_{t>0}$ be a collection of random variables such that $X_t:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $\mathscr F$-to-Borel measurable.

Fix $t_0>0$ and let $$A\equiv\{\omega\in\Omega\,|\,t\mapsto X_t(\omega) \text{ is continuous at $t_0$}\}.$$ Is there an easy way to show that $A\in\mathscr F$? Is it true to begin with? Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: An example worth keeping in mind is $$X_t=\mathbf 1_{T\in t\mathbb Q},$$ where $T$ is some given positive random time with continuous distribution. Then, for each $t$, $X_t=0$ almost surely, but, for every $\omega$, the function $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is discontinuous at every $t$. To get a situation where your $A$ is not measurable, assume that $\mathcal F$ is complete (contains every nullset) and consider $$X_t=\mathbf 1_{T\in t\mathbb Q}\mathbf 1_E,$$ for some given $E$. Then, for every $t_0$, $A=\Omega\setminus E$ hence every $E$ not in $\mathcal F$ yields some $A$ not in $\mathcal F$.

Comment: @Did : In your counterexample, unless mistaken $X_t$ is not measurable (because of E is not in $\mathcal{F}$), but the fact is that $X_t$ is measurable in triple_sec's problem am I missing something ? Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge Note that $\{X_t\ne0\}=E\cap\{T\in t\mathbb Q\}\subseteq\{T\in t\mathbb Q\}$ and $P(T\in t\mathbb Q)=0$ hence, *if $\mathcal F$ contains every nullset*, $\{X_t\ne0\}$ is indeed in $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Here is a reference for the case that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is *assumed* to be càdlàg: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1268152/